# Consuming Java APIs that use JetBrains annotations in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

Consider the following Java API:

```java
public interface Recipe {

    @NotNull
    List<Ingredient> getIngredients();

    void AddOptionalIngredient(@Nullable Ingredient ingredient);
}
```

When you implement this from Kotlin, IntelliJ will insert the correct nullable modifiers because of the `@NotNull` and `@Nullable` annotations:

```kotlin
class CakeRecipe : Recipe {

    // Return type is non-nullable...
    fun getIngredients(): MutableList<Ingredient> { ... }

    // Parameter type is nullable...
    fun addOptionalIngredient(ingredient: Ingredient?) { ... }
}
```

There is still a problem with the implementation; notably, that Java's `List<T>` maps to `MutabeList<T>` in Kotlin, although, I can make this change manually:

```kotlin
class CakeRecipe : Recipe {

    // Return type is read-only (or, unmodifiable)
    fun getIngredients(): List<Ingredient> { ... }

    ...
}
```

I recently found out about the `@Unmodifiable` annotation, and assumed that JetBrains would respect this annotation in the same way that it respects `@NotNull` and `@Nullable`, therefore my Java API looks like this:

```java
public interface Recipe {

    @NotNull
    @Unmodifiable List<Ingredient> getIngredients();

    void AddOptionalIngredient(@Nullable Ingredient ingredient);
}
```

But, the Kotlin implementation still implements `MutableList<T>`:

```kotlin
class CakeRecipe : Recipe {

    // @Unmodifiable not respected by IDE
    fun getIngredients(): MutableList<Ingredient> { ... }

    ...
}
```

What is the purpose of `@Unmodifiable`, and is it possible (with, or without an annotation) to get Kotlin to implement `List<T>` where the corresponding Java API is `List<T>`?

Comment: Looks like a missing feature in the Kotlin compiler. Please note these annotations are not standardized. Multiple companies provide their own for performing some kind of static code analysis. JetBrains' annotations were created mostly for the code analysis in IntelliJ. Still, I think it would be a nice addition to respect them in the Kotlin compiler.

Comment: Since you can update the code manually, is your question about the generation of the snippet in the IDE? Or is it about forbidding returning `MutableList` when `@Unmodifiable List` is expected as return type in the Java interface?

Comment: To be fair, the `@Unmodifiable` and `@UnmodifiableView` annotations are both defined as having
`@Target(TYPE_USE)`
which doesn't sound like what you want anyway.

By contrast, `@NotNull` and `@Nullable` are defined to have
`@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, LOCAL_VARIABLE, TYPE_USE})`.

Comment: @Joffrey I guess the former (generation of the snippet in the IDE), since forbidding `MutableList<T>` isn't actually possible?

Comment: I might be wrong, but IIRC with strict JSR 305 mode (`-Xjsr305=strict` compiler argument), you get compile errors on misuses of nullable/non-nullable types in Kotlin for things declared in java with the proper JSR-305 annotations, including method overrides like this. So I guess it would be possible in general, it just hasn't been done for `@Unmodifiable`